# I am using sql server 2000 and having sql server management application of 2017 when i am trying to connecting my sql to spring boot i am get error

Tags: java, sql-server, spring-boot, middleware

Whenever I am trying to connect my SQL server to the spring boot in java with the use of Connection string I am getting these two error

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Driver com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver claims to not accept jdbcUrl

> Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed;

I am using this connection string

```
-->  spring.datasource.url="jdbc:sqlserver://Server name;" + "databaseName=databasename;"
     spring.datasource.username=userid
     spring.datasource.password=password
```

and using this driver class

```
-->  spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver

     spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect
```

Comment: Why are you *still* using SQL Server 2000 would be my question; it hasn't had ***any support*** for over a decade. The last train to upgrade that instance  departed a *long* time ago; you really need to get onto a supported version.

Comment: ya you are correct but my company having servers on this thats why i need to use 2000 sql server